# When i install oh my posh get an error , how to fix it?

Tags: oh-my-posh

[image]

how to fix it?

help me fix an error
Oh My Posh Error:

open https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/v7.59.0/themes/default.omp.json: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Maintainer here. Can you create an issue on GitHub? That way I can help you see what’s wrong. What I need is the following:

- oh-my-posh lines added to your profile
- a bit of patience

https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. As a workaround I included the full path to the theme in my `$PROFILE`.

```
oh-my-posh init pwsh --config $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes\default.omp.json | Invoke-Expression
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty late here, if anyone gets this error in future, make sure you are using powershell not command prompt